# Composite primary key sql relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, primary-key, sql-server-2012

I need to create a relationship between `ReportID` which is part of a composite primary key. 
This is my code written for Microsoft SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE Tableone
(
    ReportID varchar UNIQUE,
    Date date,
    Line ommited

PRIMARY KEY (ReportNumber, Date)
)

CREATE TABLE Tabletwo
(
    Line omitted
    Line ommited
    ReportID varchar UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tableone(ReportID),
    Line ommited

    PRIMARY KEY (XX, XXX, ReportID)
)
```

UPDATE: We have specifically been asked to set both `ReportID` and `Date` as the primary key in `Tableone` but to just  reference `ReportID` in `Tabletwo`.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you have a **composite** primary key, then **all** foreign keys that reference it **MUST** use all columns of the composite primary key. So in your case - `TableTwo` **MUST** reference `TableOne(ReportNumber, Date)`

Comment: @marc_s : not, they don't have...

Comment: @a1ex07: see my answer - that's what I'm saying there, in more detail (comment is too short for that much detail)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a **composite** primary key, then **all** foreign key constraints that reference it must use **all columns** of the composite primary key.

So in your case - `TableTwo` **must** reference `TableOne(ReportID, Date)`

The only way around this would be to create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `TableOne (ReportID)` - then you can create a foreign key reference to that unique constraint alone.

But that then begs the question: why isn't `ReportID` alone the primary key, if it's already unique (since you can put a `UNIQUE INDEX` on it) and NOT NULL (since it's part of the compound PK) ?

Step 1: create the `UNIQUE INDEX`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UIX_TableOne ON dbo.TableOne(ReportID);
```

Step 2: create the foreign key from `TableTwo`:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableTwo
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TableTwo_TableOne
FOREIGN KEY(ReportID) REFERENCES dbo.TableOne(ReportID)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately the coursework specification says we musts set the tables up this way.  I have already set the column to unique with the UNIQUE statement. How do you set a UNIQUE INDEX?

Comment: @marc_s : I think that's incorrect : A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: @a1ex07: yes - that's what I said in my response - no? If you don't want to reference the primary key (**all** columns), then you can put a unique index on a column... read my answer!

Comment: @marc_s : oops, my bad :) I paid too much attention to what you have in bold in your answer...

Comment: Note however, that if ReportID is unique in its own right then (ReportID, Date) cannot possibly be the primary key of TableOne - because it is not a candidate key. The constraint called "PRIMARY KEY" in SQL is technically a poorly named superkey constraint in this instance.

Comment: @sqlvogel: yes, I agree - my point exactly. That's what I was trying to say: if `ReportID` in itself is unique and NOT NULL - then **IT** should be the primary key. But see the OP's note - for whatever reason, someone else seems to have decided not to use that as their PK - even though all relational laws would require `ReportID` in itself to be the PK for that table ...

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your help unfortunately I seem to be getting an error on creating the primary key within Tabletwo. The error is happening on this line: `PRIMARY KEY (XX, XXX, ReportID)` with the following error message: "Msg 1911, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Column name 'ReportID' does not exist in the target table or view. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 4 Could not create constraint. See previous errors."

Comment: @Patty: read the error message - that column does not exist - typo? Is it called `ReportNumber` instead?

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your help and patience- it was a spelling mistake on ReportID.