# Save many-to-many data from xml file in stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

want create store procedure of these tables for my xml file as i given up

```
select * from pro.Proposals
select * from dbo.[pro.ProposalDetails
select * from dbo.[pro.ProposalSlabs]
```

[image]

i want many-to-many save data in table through xml file in stored procedure using sql server*, i send you my xml file with created stored procedure.
**XML FILE**

ML FILE

```
<root> <subCompanyId>1</subCompanyId> <code>sdfgsdgsdfgsdfg</code> <countryId>1</countryId> <groupId>1</groupId> <branchId>1</branchId> <isBranchProposal>1</isBranchProposal> <countryRateListId>1</countryRateListId> <yearsNo>1</yearsNo> <subTotal>1.0</subTotal> <total>1.0</total> <companyId>1</companyId> <createdBy>AF@fdfsae</createdBy> <userAttemptNo>1</userAttemptNo> <isApproved>1</isApproved> <details>
```

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52665468/edit) your question. Don't post important information in the comments. i've added the data into the question, however, since it was a comment it has lost any formatting. i would suggest updating it to be readable.

Comment: Edit your question... Stop spamming the comments, please.

Comment: This stream of comments come across as general plea to do your job for you. This is not a free code writing service that exists to provide instant help when you are in over your head. Don't post pictures of tables. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 I sense you are desperate for help but this question is not answerable at this point because it lacks the details. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: *"I complete send my work plz anyone help me it's must for my career Thanks"* This isn't going to help you get answers from the community. The last thing you should be doing to relying on a (somewhat) anonymous community to help you keep your job. I'm afraid what you are asking is still completely unclear. You XML is unformatted, and unreadable as a result. When posting on Stack Overflow, the **volunteers** expect some due diligence. Explain what you're trying to do, provide sample data (not as a an image), show what you've tried, and **importantly**, ask a **specific** question.

Answer (score 0):

Resolving a many to many relationship is done in SQL via resolving it into 2 one to many relationships and establishing an intermediary "bridge". Example: students and classes. multiple students have multiple classes. You establish one student table and one class table and the intermediary table is the "enrollment" table.
This has been addressed in SOF already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497395/resolve-many-to-many-relationship) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210389/normalization-of-many-to-many-relation-in-sql)

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: I think OP is asking how to store a many to many data relationship in a normalized SQL DB.

Comment: Looks like he already has all the tables created and wants to populate/update them with data from given XML file.

Comment: correct, I would think that the xml file delivers data junk, one problem being many to many relationships. 
It is also a miracle to me why OP wants to create a "procedure" on the SQL server side rather than solving this in Java, tbh.